# Read source of popup windows opened with javacript:void()?

Tags: asp.net, regex, webclient

I am going to do my best to ask this question as clearly as possible. Is it possible to write some asp.net code that can go through and read the source of pop up windows that are normally opened by clicking a javascript:void() link. Basically i want to read the source of said popups, extract specific links and then render those links in a web page. What i am trying to achieve is a way to make it easy to download the videos of the Senate floor - their videos open in a new popup that uses silverlight. The mp4 file location is in the source so i want to read that url. I did something similar using the code below. The difference was that the mp4 links were in main page. The code read the source and then outputted the video links so i could just right click and do a save as. This was for the videos at the German security conference. Apologies if this is not seen as a constructive question and ends up being closed.

```
Protected Sub btnClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
    Dim r As New Regex("\bhttps?://\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|mp3|mp4|3gp)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)


    Dim c As New WebClient
    Dim s As String = c.DownloadString(txtUrl.Text)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder


    For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
        sb.Append("<a href=" & m.Value & ">" & m.Value & "</a><br />")
        divLinks.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to access (the landing page)?

Comment: http://www.senate.gov/floor/index.htm

Comment: The videos are inside an iframe which points to this: http://floor.senate.gov/proceedings why not read them directly from there?